# CakePHP 2.3 and Active Directory/LDAP

Tags: cakephp, active-directory, ldap, cakephp-2.3

I've been looking for a good authentication tutorial/solution using CakePHP 2.3 and Active Directory and am coming up dry.  Not for want of trying, I found some good info for Cake 1.3 (took awhile to figure that out) and I found Analgorithms CakePHP 2.3 idBroker plugin which seems to be way more than I need but also seems to not work.

Stuff I found:
http://abakalidis.blogspot.com/search/label/Active%20Directory
http://www.analogrithems.com/rant/2012/01/03/cakephp-2-0-ldapauth/

Not much seems to work. I'm relatively new to cake, so I may just be messing up the install of IdBroker above, as that's the only hit google comes back with.

I'd just like to get the point where I can debug connecting to my LDAP source and verifying the authentication.  If someone knows of a good tutorial, awesome, point me to it.

Otherwise I'm stuck trying to figure out the Idbroker plugin that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What functionality do you need? I had to work with LDAP recently (Codeigniter), for authentication and pulling a bit about each user's groups to lock down different sections. Wound up writing my own class, which wasn't as bad as I thought. Might not be a bad way to go.

Comment: I really need the most basic, I just want to authenticate against our Activie Directory server, I don't want to store any user data locally.  It's an internal tool, so I'm fine with verifying credentials in AD then storing login information in the session.

Comment: It would seem this should be straight forward, I need a model that defines a user as an ldap target, some way to define the ldap data source and bind controls and then a way to plugin to the authenticate methods of Cake.

Comment: If you do not need to integrate the solution into Cake too much and are happy to use a non-Cake objects, please take a look at [AD-X](https://github.com/Alaneor/AD-X). Authenticating a user against Active Directory is then simple as instantiating the ADX\Core\Link and binding with user's credentials using `$link->bind()`.

Comment: Did you get this solved?

Comment: You can add a customized authorize object, see documentation : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authorize-objects or maybe this question can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363270/ldap-authentication-with-cakephp